# UILabel Shadow Has Unwanted Cut Off

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, shadow

I have a UILabel that I add a shadow to. The UILabel shows up and so does the shadow, but the leftmost shadow is cut off so that it is in line with the edge of the text. I moved the position of the label to see if it was being covered by a view, but everything stayed the same. I also took out the sizeToFit, and it stayed the same. Here is the initialization of the label:

```
    UILabel *scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    scoreLabel.text = text;
    [scoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize]];
    scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];

    scoreLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];
    scoreLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-10.0, 2.0);
    scoreLabel.clipsToBounds = NO;

    [scoreLabel sizeToFit];

    scoreLabel.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of interest, what font is that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I added this and the cut off went away:

```
scoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: That's not really a "correct" solution :) but if it worked you - vert well

Comment: I did a View Inspector and the label was on top @sha, but I noticed the text was on the left edge of the label, so I added this and now it is centered and doesn't cut off.

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you tried to achieve using left alignment as well.

Comment: The shadow of my labels are also cut off, but changing the alignment doesn't work for me... I guess I have to make the bounds "shadow-aware" but couldn't figure out yet. Setting clipsToBounds to false doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with a custom font and solved it by subclassing UILabel and adding the `shadowOffset` to `intrinsicContentSize` with this override:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize  {
    get {
        let s = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: s.width + abs(shadowOffset.width), height: s.height + abs(shadowOffset.height))
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add

```
scoreLabel.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: still has the same behavior

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: That does look like something else cutting it above. Might want to run view inspector and see what exactly

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution you want:

```swift
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.firstLineHeadIndent = someInset // can be shadowBlur and/or shadowRadius
style.headIndent = someInset
style.tailIndent = -someInset // must be negative since its at the end (tail)

let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some Text")
attrString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: .init(location: 0, attrString.length)
let label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 0 // not necessary
label.attributedText = attrString
```